# jQuery DataTable: Disabling sorting for specific columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have 6 columns in my jQuery Data table and want to disable sorting for the first and last column.

I have used the following code:

```
$('#UserDetails').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
          { "bSortable": false },
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          { "bSortable": false }
      ]
});
```

This code disables sorting for the last column but not the first.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle which reproduces the problem? I am not able to -> http://jsfiddle.net/fw0z7sc3/ What version of dataTables are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#UserDetails').dataTable( {
      "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0,5 ] }
       ]
});
```

where 0,5 are the indexes of the columns that you want to exlude from the sort

Comment: Still the same issue continues. The 6th column becomes unsortable but first column still sorts

Comment: can you reproduce it on a fiddle so I can see it?

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery datatable usually we use last column for sending extrdata/payload so if you have 6 visible columns actually they are 7 columns so:

```
$('#UserDetails').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
          { "bSortable": false },
          {"bSortable": true},
          {"bSortable": true},
          {"bSortable": true},  
          {"bSortable": true},
          {"bSortable": false}, 
          {"bSortable": false, "bVisible":false} //invisible column
      ]
});
```

Comment: Generates error that there is no 6th column defined. So I added a new column but still same problem continues..

Answer (score 0):

For 1.10.13, you can use the following

```
$('#UserDetails').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [0,5]
        }
    ]
);
```